# Validating dates while creating nodes

Tags: nodes, entities, datetime

I have a content type of book leave. When the user created the node. I want to check whether the start date is less than or equal to end date. Start date and end date are date fields.

How to acheive this?

Comment: This will be default validation if you use http://drupal.org/project/date module

Comment: How can i collect the number of days between the dates?

Comment: This is a default validation performed by date module. But if you to do some action during node creation, you can drupal hooks like hook_node_insert, hook_node_presave, hook_node_update, hook_node_validate, hook_node_submit etc.